# Json with PHP mysql and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I have a strange problem..

When i try to access my json code with the corresponding number [0], [1] etc.. I just get the first character of the object.

First of my code:

**test2.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['getCustomersArray'])){
$runQuery = mysql_query($Query) or
        die("SQL: $Query)<br />".mysql_error()); 
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($runQuery); 
$array = array(array());

for($i = 0;$i <= 2; $i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($runQuery);
    $array[$i]['namn'] = $row['fornamn'];

}
    print json_encode($array);
}
```

**scriptfile.js**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "test2.php",
    data: "getCustomersArray=true",
    datatype: "JSON",
    cache: false,
    success: function(json) {
            console.log(json[0]);
     }
});
```

The result (from console.log(json[0])):

```
[
```

The result from just console.log(json):

```
[{"namn":"the first name"},{"namn":"The secound name"},{"namn":"the third name"}]
```

Im not sure why the squarebrackets are there but maybe they should be?

Ive been fuzzing with this problem for a while now and im sure its something stupid. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an incorrect option in the AJAX settings,

```
datatype: "json",
```

It should be:

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: try json in lowercase. `dataType: "json"`

Comment: @Martin Aha, I thought jQuery lowercases it by default.

Comment: I also thought that to be honest, but it seems not, haha!

Answer (score 1):

```
datatype: "JSON",
```

supposed to be

```
dataType: "json",  // json in lowercase and T has to be captalized
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['getCustomersArray'])){
$runQuery = mysql_query($Query) or
    die("SQL: $Query)<br />".mysql_error()); 
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($runQuery); 
$array = array(array());

for($i = 0;$i <= 2; $i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($runQuery);
    $array[$i]['namn'] = $row['fornamn'];
}
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
print json_encode($array);
}
```

Here you need to set the content-type to application/json and set the correct charset to avoid any cross-browser issues. Take a look at the following tutorial from my website which should cover all of this and perhaps some improvements to your code: [PHP jQuery Search Tutorial - using JSON object the proper way](http://www.revillwebdesign.com/php-jquery-search-tutorial/)

Hope this helps :)